# C++ fwrite() in hex

Tags: c++, fwrite

Writing code with Winsock.
I currently have this:

```
fwrite(buff, 1, len, stdout);
```

How to do it like:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
printf( "%02x ", unsigned char (buff[i]) );
}
printf( "\n" );
```

Or should I just remove the fwrite and use the print instead?
I wanted to write it to stdout, cuz I have my option to either write to stdout of write to file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fprintf` (see [the docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/)) is like `printf` but to an arbitrary file:

```
fprintf(stdout, "%02x ", unsigned char (buff[i]));
```

Comment: An `unsigned char` will be promoted to `int` automatically because it is in the variable argument part of the argument list to `fprintf()` and default promotions apply to those.  The cast to `unsigned char` may do some good, too; if the `char` type is signed, the cast prevents sign-extension of characters with the high bit set (0x80..0xFF).  (And, strictly strictly, `%x` expects an `unsigned int` — it will treat what is passed as if it were an `unsigned int`, anyway.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Thanks! - I didn't know that.  Answer amended.

Comment: I see that; I'll leave my first comment as it may help others; I'll delete this one shortly, and it is up to you whether you delete your comment.